# Is it possible to add a not shared variable to a prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a function that would retrofit some of my prototypes with some common functions.

I would also like to add object instance specific variables through this mechanic, sorta like:

```
function give_weird_container(target) {
    target.<somehow instance specific, not prototype>.underlying_container = [];
    target.prototype.container_func = function(x, y, z) {
        return this.underlying_container[x + 2*y + 3*z];
    }
}

function my_class1() {}

give_weird_container(my_class1);
```

And now when I create a new instance of my_class1, it should have a property "uderlying_container" that would act the same as if I called

```
this.underlying_container = [];
```

in the constructor.

Is that possible while remaining in the confines of the give_weird_container function?

Comment: You mean like? `target.underlying_container = [];`

Comment: `somehow instance specific` but there is no instance in the function ???

Comment: @ankitbug94 well, yes, the property would be added to all new instances

Comment: @ankitbug94 that makes no sense

Comment: @user81993 Now I see you want unshared array. I thought you want variable only on specific instance. My mistake but using `unique to each instance ` would be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a not shared variable to a prototype?

No. All properties on the prototype are shared. Instance specific properties can only be set *after* an instance was created.

You could however add a *getter* to the prototype that will create an instance specific property if it doesn't exist.

For example:

```
Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'underlying_container', {
  get: function() {
    if (!this._underlying_container) {
      this._underlying_container = [];
    }
    return this._underlying_container;
  },
});
```

The getter is shared, but the value returned is per instance.

If you don't like the fact that the getter is executed every time `this.underlying_container` is accessed, you could replace it with an instance property when the prototype property is called the first time:

```
Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'underlying_container', {
  get: function() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'underlying_container', {value: []});
    return this. underlying_container;
  },
});
```

`Object.defineProperty(this, 'underlying_container', {value: []});` will create a new property with the same name on the *instance* thus shadowing the getter defined on the prototype.

---

To pick up @4castle's suggestion, if it is possible to mutate instances directly, then you could do something like this instead, which is a bit less "magic":

```
var give_weird_container = (function() {
    function container_func(x, y, z) {
        return this.underlying_container[x + 2*y + 3*z];
    };

    return function(target) {
      target.underlying_container = [];
      target.container_func = container_func;
    };
}());

function my_class1() {}

var instance = new my_class1();

give_weird_container(instance);
```

Comment: This feels like a hack in order to do something they shouldn't be doing. Basic inheritance seems like what they need.

Comment: @4castle no he does not need basic prototypal inheritance because I am not sure but may be the OP does not want to change the content inside target( my_class1)

Comment: @4castle: Inheritance only works if it is possible to change the class definition, which may not be possible or not desired in this case. To me it seems the OP wants something like mixins.

Comment: ankitbug94 is correct, I'd like to keep the code I have to maintain to a minimum or at least not spread out through the entire project.

Comment: @ankitbug94 Prototypical inheritance would be overkill. It sounds like they need to make a wrapper function that sets the field they want and then calls the constructor.

Comment: @4castle: That would require to change every callsite where an instance is created. If there aren't that many then I agree, that would be cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could give `my_class1` a wrapper function that calls the constructor and then sets the field:

```
function give_weird_container(target) {
    target.prototype.container_func = function(x, y, z) {
        return this.underlying_container[x + 2*y + 3*z];
    }
    return function() {
        var obj = new target();
        obj.underlying_container = [];
        return obj;
    }
}

function my_class1() {}

my_class1 = give_weird_container(my_class1);
```

Comment: What about arguments passed to the constructor? Also, this will make `var foo = new my_class1(); console.log(foo instanceof my_class1);` return `false`. Might not be important, but worth to point out. Or is the replaced `my_class1` to be called without `new`?

Comment: @Felix The returned function can be called with or without `new` and it will behave the same. The `instanceof` operator will return `true` as far as I can tell. The parameters would need to be specified.

Comment: *"The instanceof operator will return true as far as I can tell."* Not if the function is called with `new` (see https://jsfiddle.net/bthzwphe/). *" The parameters would need to be specified"* In which case it wouldn't be possible to apply this to different classes. Again, not necessarily a bad thing, but maybe worth to point out.

Comment: @FelixKling Since the class is being wrapped so without new will also return false as `my_class1` is the new anonymous function returned from `give_weird_container` https://jsfiddle.net/bthzwphe/1/